# Nesting projects within projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nested, namespaces, project

Please forgive my ignorance - I'm not an IT pro (just a 'hobby' programmer) but can anyone advise if it's possible to nest a vs2017 C# project within another project?

I'm thinking of something like:

- Solution A

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3

    - Project 3A
    - Project 3B

Specifically, I've got a Datalayer project in which I'd like to nest a couple of sub-projects, one to an SQL Server DB and the other to a Neo4j Graph DB.
Ideally, I'd like to reference just the Datalayer (Project 3) from Project 1 or 2...
I suppose I'm thinking of something similar to dividing functionality using Namespaces?

Comment: 1 project = 1 namespace. I suppose project 1 is HMI, project 2 is business layer and 3 is DAL. 1 has a reference to 2, 2 has a reference to 3.

Comment: @Cid not necessarily true, 1 project can contain multiple namespaces. But generally you want a project to only contain one namespace and sub-namespaces, eg. ProjectA containing namespaces ProjectA, ProjectA.Foo, ProjectA.Bar

Comment: Did you see this MSFT doc?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/nesting-projects?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot nest projects. But you can nest namespaces, like `namespace SolutionA.Project3.Project3B {}` 
Tip: if you want your folder structure to match your namespace structure, first create a folder in Windows Explorer. Than add a folder with the same name in the solution explorer. Then simply add classes etc. to that folder in the solution explorer.

Comment: Are you sure?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/nesting-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: in the past I was able to easily create Modules in Rider which created nested projects. A project that had 2 projects as children and you can even see the setup in the .sln file within the GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/nesting-projects?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Rider has this as a selection but I noticed if you do this in Visual studio you get the same outcome. Right click in the solution, select Add, "New Solution Folder" and then right click that solution folder, select Add, "New Project". Now you have nested projects. As far as I can see it looks the same. You might make a main project in there and then have 2 other projects reference from that project but in all they are grouped in a solution folder.